# Guess the mime type of a file in elisp?

Tags: files

Is there a builtin function to guess the MIME type of a file in Emacs Lisp? I would like to display the MIME type for files in Dired buffers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. In standard library `mailcap.el` you will find functions that deal with mime types.

For example, `mailcap-mime-types` gives a list of known mime types - `M-: (mailcap-mime-types)` returns something like this:

```el
("text/plain" "audio/x-mpeg" "audio/aiff" "application/x-annotator" 
 "audio/ulaw" "video/x-msvideo" "application/x-bcpio" "application/octet-stream"
 "application/x-netcdr" "application/x-cpio" "application/x-csh" "text/css" 
 "application/x-dvi" "text/x-patch" "test/x-patch" "application/emacs-lisp" 
 "application/postscript" "text/x-setext" "image/x-fax" "image/gif" 
 "application/x-hdf" "application/mac-binhex40" "text/html" "image/x-icon" "image/ief"
 "image/jpeg" "image/x-macpaint" "application/x-troff-man" "application/x-troff-me"
 "application/mif" "video/quicktime" "video/x-sgi-movie" "audio/x-mpeg2" 
 "video/mpeg" "application/x-troff-ms" "application/x-netcdf" "application/oda"
 "image/x-portable-bitmap" "application/pdf" "image/portable-graymap" "image/pict"
 "image/png" "image/x-portable-anymap" "image/portable-pixmap" "image/x-raster"
 "image/x-rgb" "application/rtf" "text/richtext" "application/x-sh" 
 "application/x-stuffit" "application/sieve" "audio/basic" "text/dns" 
 "application/x-wais-source" "archive/tar" "application/x-tcl" 
 "application/x-tex" "application/texinfo" "image/x-targa" "image/tiff" 
 "application/x-troff" "text/tab-separated-values" "x-world/x-vrml" 
 "audio/x-wav" "application/vnd.ms-excel" "image/xbm" "image/xpm" 
 "image/windowdump" "application/zip" "text/x-org" "application/x-x509-ca-cert"
 "application/x-x509-user-cert" "application/dvi" "application/x-emacs-lisp" 
 "application/x-tar" "application/x-latex" "application/latex" 
 "application/tex" "application/pgp-keys" "message/rfc822" "image/x-xwd" "text/enriched")
```

And for example, `mailcap-extension-to-mime` returns mime types applicable to files with given extensions.

The code in `mailcap-file-default-commands` shows some of what you can do.  This part, for example, returns all unique MIME types for the given FILES:

```el
(mailcap-delete-duplicates
   (mapcar (lambda (file) (mailcap-extension-to-mime (file-name-extension file t)))
           files))
```